# Spider to download images does not seem to work though i have pil installed

Tags: scrapy

I am a newbie to scrapy.I am trying to write a spider to download images.for using the image pipeline,is installing PIL sufficient?My PIL is located in
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL

How do I include it in my Scrapy project?

**settings file:**

```
BOT_NAME = 'paulsmith'
BOT_VERSION = '1.0'

ITEM_PIPELINES = ['scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline']
IMAGE_STORE = '/home/jay/Scrapy/paulsmith/images'


SPIDER_MODULES = ['paulsmith.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'paulsmith.spiders'
DEFAULT_ITEM_CLASS = 'paulsmith.items.PaulsmithItem'
USER_AGENT = '%s/%s' % (BOT_NAME, BOT_VERSION)
```

**Items file:**

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class PaulsmithItem(Item):

    image_urls=Field()  
    image = Field()
    pass
```

**Spider code**

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from paulsmith.items import PaulsmithItem

class PaulSmithSpider(BaseSpider):
    name="Paul"
    allowed_domains=["http://www.paulsmith.co.uk/uk-en/shop/mens"]
    start_urls=["http://www.paulsmith.co.uk/uk-en/shop/mens/jeans"]

    def parse(self,response):
        item= PaulsmithItem()
        #open('paulsmith.html','wb').write(response.body)
        hxs=HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        #sites=hxs.select('//div[@class="category-products"]')
        item['image_urls']=hxs.select("//div[@class='category-products']//a/img/@src").extract()
        #for site in sites:
            #print site.extract()
            #image = site.select('//a/img/@src').extract()
        return item


SPIDER = PaulSmithSpider()
```

Comment: in my settings i have registered the item pipeline and the images store.My spider crawls the website,returns the image_urls but i have no image.

Comment: ITEM_PIPELINES = ['scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline']. When i run scrapy crawl "spidername" it is not showing any error.The part which i dont understand is i dont have contrib folder in scrapy so how do i import imagepipeline??I imported it in my pipeline.py file.I dont know if it is correct

Comment: If you're not sure, please edit your answer to show your spider code, items.py and settings files.

Comment: okiee will update the above answer.will include my settings file and items.py

Comment: Have updated my answer and have included all the 3 files and my pipelines.py file is similar to that of the custom images pipeline code below.Guide me as to why i am not able to download the images

Answer (score 0):

You may have not set IMAGES_STORE = '/path/to/valid/dir'

morever, try to use a Custom Images pipeline like this:

```
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request

class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
        if not image_paths:
            raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
        item['image_paths'] = image_paths
        return item
```

You can check whether image_urls are requested from method "get_media_requests"

reference: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/images.html

Comment: actually i have used the custom images pipeline.My doubt is that i have to edit my pipelines.py file right?and i dont understand the from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline statement

Comment: For scraping images you will also need the Python Image Library:
Please visit:
http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/#pil117